# Ionic 4 cannot use the HTTP plugin in without cordova anymore?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4

Coming from Ionic 3 I am building my first Ionic 4 app now. 
I want to use the HTTP plugin:

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/http

In Ionic 3 I was able to use the plugin and test it in the function since no native functionality was needed. Now, in Ionic 4 I get an error:

> Native: tried calling HTTP.post, but Cordova is not available.

So I just want to confirm that I cannot use the HTTP requests in the browser anymore. Is that correct?

It'S kind of bothering having to use an emulator for all my development tests now...

Comment: It won't work in ionic 4 without cordova for the moment. You can check if you are running on a device and make a http request with ajax if not

Comment: you have to create a wrapper service and do check if in the device or in browser then accordingly you have to handle

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use https://github.com/sneas/ionic-native-http-connection-backend#readme

This plugin will fallback to angular's HttpClient when in the browser and know to use the native http plugin when on the device.

Per the README:

This strategy allows developers to use Angular's HttpClient transparently in both environments: Browser and Device.

With this you don't have to use any http cordova specific code in your project at all.